# How to remove a user from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have many users in Jenkins that have automatically come from SVN. One of our developers left the project and I removed him from the SVN. However, his contacts are not removed from Jenkins and I cannot find a place in Jenkins where I could remove users from. Any ideas on how to remove users from Jenkins?

Comment: The way Jenkins handles users is just ridiculous. Good luck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you need to remove or replace the user from, all the times they exist, in the build.xml file(s) which are under the jobs directory then the name of the job and the builds directory.

Comment: That worked. Check the Jenkins *People* page. If you deleted non-existant users and they pop up again, it's because they are remembered in the `build.xml` as `culprits`.
In the *People* page you can see to which job they are associated. Then search the `build.xml` files and remove users there.
In my case i didn't care so much on keeping the build so i just deleted the builds.

Comment: After doing this I had to restart Jenkins. You might need to too. yourjenkins.com/safeRestart

Comment: In my case, in addition to deleting all build.xml files, i had to update user info first before deleting them again.

Answer (score 46):

I couldn't find the delete option. I went here and found a relevant but unhelpful answer. So I just tried:

```
http://<jenkins.url>/user/<username>/delete
```

I got redirected to an existing page \o/ There was a button asking to confirm the deletion. I clicked and the user was removed.

Hope this helps

PS: I just found how to do it right: Go to "Manage Jenkins" > "Manage Users" and click the delete button on the same row (far right) of the user you want to delete

Comment: Manage Users is not available in 1.542

Comment: But this way everyone can delete every existing user! Right?

Comment: @coffeMug - I just tried this and it works. I'm not sure if you can delete EVERY existing user (users with higher permissions than you have, for example), but at the least, for users in the same ranking as you, this is possible.

Comment: If you are trying this hack with more recent Jenkins versions, you'll need to temporarily turn off the CSRF protection.

Answer (score 10):

If you go to the **People** view, you can click a user and then choose **Delete** in the left-hand menu (if you have *Administer* access).

You could also delete the folder `[jenkins-root]/Users/[username]` and re-start Jenkins.

Comment: for some reason for some people there is a delete button, for others there is not :) in this case for this user, there is no delete button.

Comment: This is just ridiculous... If I change the email address of the person I want to remove, it will create a duplicate user. The duplicate can be deleted but the original user cannot. It seems that I have to delete all builds containing any mentioning of this user! How can big enterprises with high user volatility ever use Jenkins when users linked to builds cannot be deleted? :) In a way it's funny, but this is also quite a serious issue...

Comment: Oh, and my users are not visible in the jenkins user path you mentioned above.